# is this such set always a closed set? (norms)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Say let $(X,d)$ be a normed vector space, equipped with some norm $||.||$, then would the set $S:=\{x\in X:||x||=1\}$ always be a closed set for any type of norm and any type of normed vector space? Can we prove it or disprove it straight from the definition of closed set and norm?

Comment: You can prove it via the triangle inequality. For any vector with norm $\neq1$, you can find a ball such that there is no overlap with $S$, which can be shown by the inequality. Then, take the union over all such balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangle inequality shows that $| \|x\|-\|y\|| \leq \|x-y\|$ so the map $x \to \|x\|$ is a continuous function. The inverse image of $\{1\}$ under this map is therefore a closed set.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. How do we know that the map is cts?

Comment: The metric in the space is defined by $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. The inequality I have written show that $d(x,y) <\epsilon$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$ where $f(x)=\|x\|$. This proves uniform continuous of $f$. @DonThousand

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense